# How to apply jquery UI buttons to asp:Button

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

How do I apply jQueryUI styles to an asp:Button. Here is the problem: jqueryUI button requires you to have the following format `<button>Test button</button>`

When I try to use an asp button server control, `<asp:Button />`, asp:Button renders as `<input type=button>Test button </input>`

**Update** : I get the standard button styling that jquery provides. However, when I want to make a toolbar out of it, like in this example : http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#toolbar, the standard asp:Button fails me....or maybe i am missing something.
Thanks in advance,

Sashidhar Kokku

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how you do it:  Add the following to your initialize function:

```
$(function () {
        //Converting asp buttons to html buttons
        $('input:submit, input:reset').each(function () {
            $(this).replaceWith('<button type="submit" name="' + $(this).attr('name') + '" class="' + $(this).attr('class') + '" id="' + $(this).attr('id') + '" >' + $(this).val() + '</button>');
        });

  //Adding button icons .....
  $(".createbutton").button({
     icons: { primary: "ui-icon-circle-plus" } 
   });
```

Comment: `$("input[id$='btnAwesome']")`

Answer (score 8):

You can apply the jQuery UI button to a number of different HTML elements: <a>, <input type="button"> and so on.

```
$(function() {
    $("input[type=button]").button();
});
```

This will convert *all* <asp:Button>s on the page into jQuery UI buttons.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not apply the theme properly. Any idea or examples of its implementation anywhere would help.


Thanks,


Sashidhar Kokku

Answer (score 6):

The jQuery UI button widget [is capable of transforming](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/) the following button types:

- `<input type="button" />`
- `<input type="submit" />`
- `<button></button>`

Since the `<asp:Button>` control renders the first type of HTML, you could include the following in your master page to apply the jQuery transform to all ASP.NET buttons:

```
$("input[type=button]").button();
```

You should also 
`$("input[type=submit]").button();` 
to handle submit buttons.

Answer (score 4):

You can assign a style to the ASP.NET buttons, then use the style as a selector to selectively (pardon the pun) apply the jQuery button. For example, if you set the attribute CssClass="special" on the buttons you want to modify, then you would put the following jQuery in your page:

```
$(function() {
    $(".special").button();
});
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure jQuery UI will work fine with button input, as well any other element.
You just need to select the desired element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#<%= Button1.UniqueID %>').click(function() {

    // do something
});

});
```