# button firing click event twice

Tags: asp.net

It seems that sometimes (but not always) my button click event is being fired twice.  The fact that it seems to happen sometimes but not always is really puzzling me.  Here is my button :

```
<button id="btnSave" onserverclick="btnAddUser_Click" name="btnSave" type="submit" style="font-size:11px;font-family:Verdana;font-weight:bold;" runat="server">Save</button>
```

Comment: why you did not used asp:button instead of button ?

Comment: It is because the type button is submit. Change it to button and it will work. Explanation here : https://mzulkamal.com/blog/asp-net-web-form-html-button-tag-fires-two-times-s

Answer (score 28):

I had the same problem, and it took me a while to figure it out!
If you add type="button" to your button, it seems to fix the issue.

Comment: hmm, type="button" should be an invalid attribute for the button tag in html, I think?

Comment: …and, I am, of course, wrong! type can be button, reset, or submit. This makes perfect sense.

Comment: I was having a heck of a time with this.  My HtmlButton was `type="submit"` and the event was firing twice and causing all kinds of havoc in my database.  Changing it to `type="button"` made it work the way one would expect.

Comment: Wow, I've been strugling for years with this issue, trying to add session variables and such to check if this was a second submit, etc.  This fixes it with one quick and easy fix.

Answer (score 9):

I just came across this same problem and wanted to point out that removing the "Handles btnSave.Click" from your event will prevent it from being called twice. For Example, use this in the code behind:

```
Protected Sub btnSave_OnClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    'Do Something
End Sub
```

Instead of this:

```
Protected Sub _btnSave_OnClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    'Do Something
End Sub
```

Comment: Works for VS 2017 , NET 4.7.1, VB.NET

Comment: Also works for VS 2008,  .Net 3.5, VB ASP.NET

Answer (score 2):

Use a native ASP.NET button instead.

```
<asp:Button id="btnSave" runat="server" OnClick="btnAddUser_Click"  
     style="font-size:11px;font-family:Verdana;font-weight:bold;" Text="Save" />
```

Comment: I am using JQuery themes, so I am using the HTML button rather than the .NET version.

Comment: @user517406: You can still use jQuery themes with native ASP.NET controls, see here: [Apply jQuery UI button styles to ASP.NET buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672001/how-to-apply-jquery-ui-buttons-to-aspbutton)

Comment: Another person commented on this thread and I have the same issue, this does not add JQuery theming to my .NET buttons, why I do not know.

Comment: @user517406: have you tried applying the jQuery UI CSS classes to the button directly? either `$("input[type=button]").addClass('ui-button ui-widget');` to do it the jQuery way, or just add `CssClass="ui-button ui-widget"` to your ASP.NET button.  Let me know how that goes.

Comment: That method doesn't work with JQuery themes because it only adds a style for the default situation i.e. not to button rollover, button click etc

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the problem with wiring up of event handlers. http://geekswithblogs.net/TimH/archive/2006/10/23/94874.aspx

Try if you can just have event handler in your back end. Also, the problem could be because of the type = "Submit". Check if changing it to just Button fixes the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using code behind, don't use OnClick in ASP tag, `<button id="btnSave" name="btnSave" type="submit" style="font-size:11px;font-family:Verdana;font-weight:bold;" runat="server">Save</button>`

Comment: I have the same issue, but if I remove OnClick int the asp tag, how do I get it to fire  in the code behind? I tried it and nothing.

Comment: @RobD i have the same issue, did you find any solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is already been mentioned in different answer . Use ***type ="button"*** instead of  submit

Here is a sample code

```
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button id="btnLoadCustomerFile" class="btn btn-default" type="button" runat="server" onserverclick="btnLoadCustomerFile_Click" >Load</button>
       </span>
```

And the backend  code to handle the on click

```
 protected void btnLoadCustomerFile_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadCustomerFile();
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason:
Check your button declaration in your .aspx source.  If you have a `'runat=server'` and `onclick="button1_click"`, and you have an event handler in your code-behind (ie. .aspx.vb), 
it will cause the event to be fired twice.  Here is an example in xxx.aspx:

```
<asp:Button id="button1" onclick="button1_Click" runat="server" Text="Click Me!"></asp:Button>
```

This declaration should be:

```
<asp:Button id="button1" runat="server" Text="Click Me!"></asp:Button>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The correct way (in the ASP.NET Web Form Page), as already pointed out by couple of other contributors, is to add the **type="button"** attribute to the  element, and associate a **onserverclick** event delegate handler.

For example:

```
<button type="button" id="btnSave" runat="server" onserverclick="btnSave_ServerClick" class="btn btn-success btn-label">
    <i class="fa fa-save"></i>Save
</button>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just figured a solution for it. Remove `name="btnSave"` or change it to `"btnSave1"`. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, but quite different cause. I setup container panel defaultbutton property to the button firing twice. After removing the "**DefaultButton**" property from the **Asp:Panel** the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Just had to delve back into old school ASPX again and found this issue.

My form was set up like this.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="login" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="forgotPassword" runat="server" DefaultButton="lbtnSendLoginDetails" Visible="False">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnSendLoginDetails" runat="server" >
```

The code behind was

```
Protected Sub lbtnSendLoginDetails_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lbtnSendLoginDetails.Click
```

The answer for me was to remove the DefaultButton attribute from the Panel and add

```
TabIndex="4"
```

to the LinkButton.

Comment: and remove `Handles lbtnSendLoginDetails.Click` ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, It happens to me when I use Chrome, But not in Firefox

Answer (score 0):

It is because the button type is submit. You need to change it to button to solved the button events triggering twice. Refer this blog for further explanation.

https://mzulkamal.com/blog/asp-net-web-form-html-button-tag-fires-two-times-s

Answer (score -1):

If you are using asp.net, just use asp:button.....its clean and simple. No matter what justification i read on the net, it makes no sense that the server side handler should be called twice. 
When I add type="button", the problem is solved. However the form is not submitted when I press enter key. So that's another issue to be resolved. Using the asp:button takes care of all this.