# Why I double-click on button in some asp.net web applications?

Tags: asp.net

I am writing asp.net application. I have a little problem in button click.
In some page, the event cannot drive to server side immediately. So I need to click twice. But not on all pages. I use the same control on another page. Why does this happen on these page? I simply write the code. I search in internet and google. I cannot find the exact answer.

```
 <uc2:SaveUpdateCancelButtons ID="butCmd" runat="server" 
      OnButtonClick="butCmd_Click" TabIndex="5" />

protected void butCmd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, ButtonCommands command)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: duplicated(?) - you may find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701669/button-firing-click-event-twice

Comment: thanks @fuma.I will try :).